# Overlay DIV on samsung smart tv infolink player

Tags: javascript, html, css, samsung-smart-tv

I am aware of this thread: [How to overlay another div on the video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164496/how-to-overlay-another-div-on-the-video)

But it does not give clear answer how to display DIV on video player.

I am using samsung infolink player:

```
<object id="pluginPlayer" border=0  classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER"></object>
```

It works fine, plays my streams with no problems.

I want to overlay div on the fullscreen video, but however i try it with z-index it wont show, videoplayer is always in front of it...

DIV:

```
    <div id="osd">Test Test SHOW ME!</div>
```

DIV CSS:

```
#osd{
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
border-color: grey;
border-style: groove;
display: none;
}
```

Javascript function where i set video to full screen:

```
Player.setFullscreen = function()
{
    this.plugin.SetDisplayArea(0, 0, 960, 540);
    document.getElementById('osd').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('osd').style.zIndex = '99';
}
```

Can anyone advise how to overlay html div on video ?

Comment: Hi it is a little bit strange. Player should be every time in the farest layer... Can you share more code please?